# excel VBA SUMIF need 0 when no criteria found

Tags: vba, sumifs

all,
I am pretty new to VBA in excel. 
i work in excel 2010, and I have an excel VBA as below:

```
Dim calFormula as Variant 
calFormula = "=SUMIF($B1:$B143,""stringA"",$C1:$C143)"
```

This formula works, but when there is no "StringA" in range "$B1:$B143", then the result is empty, I want to display "0" in this situation. Then
I improve the formula as below:

```
calFormula = "SUMIF($B1:$B143,"stringA",$C1:$C143)"
newCalFormula = "=IF(ISBLANK(" & calFormula &"),0," & calFormula &")"
```

The formula is correct, but the result is still empty, no "0" replace the empty value.
Am I doing anything wrong? Can some one provide me some hint?

Thank very much
Zhihong

Comment: wrap in an if statement and set the failing condition to 0 as text

Comment: crazy ideas - try tacking on a " + 0" at the end of the formula, or maybe, " * 1"

Comment: It should return `0` when there are no `"stringA"`.  Are you sure that you do not have a custom format that shows `0` as blank cells?

Comment: @jimmy8ball, tried to change 0 as text "0", does not work, I did try a simple if(isblank(A1), "0", A1) and it works

Comment: just pseudocoding but what about =IF($B1:$B143 <> "stringA" , SUM($B1:$B143),"0"" or something similar. sorry out of office at moment so cannot test fully

Comment: @ScottCraner, I think you get the point, I tried to type in 0 in the cell, and it turns to empty. I did not change the format of the file, the number 0 works good in LibreOffice, but not in office 2010, so I did not think that is because of the format setting. I will check how to modify the format.

Comment: Highlight all the cells and change the format to "General" in the ribbon under the Home tab.

Comment: @ScottCraner, yes, you are correct. It solved the problem.  Even the SUMIF() result works. Thanks very much